# Why do we create custom partitions in Linux?

Tags: linux, partition, directory-structure

I am completely new in Linux and I installed centos VM in virtual box, at the time of installation I created partitions : /(root), boot, home and swap, so I thought that this is the same like in Windows, where we create partitions C, D and E but when I login in to Linux and go to the computer, I saw inside the /(root) there is multiple directory like root, boot, home, var, bin. So my questions are:

- Why all these are inside the root if we created the different partition of home, root. Why are they not separate?
  (I know Every directory/file in the Linux filesystem is nested under the root / directory)
- Is the home partition (we created at the time of installation) and home directory inside /(root) same?
- Why do we put /home onto a separate file system, and not also things like /usr or /var?

My mindset is like in Windows, where we create C, D and E partition,  and the C drive contains the OS or Software files and the D and E drives will be empty. So in Linux if we create these partitions, there should be /(root), boot and home, but why is here only / with everything (including boot and home partition that we created at the time of installation) inside the / that was automatically created?

(I am not asking what this individual folder does.)

Comment: *why we create the custom partition, what does it make sense to create custom partition if OS self does it for us?* Sorry, I did not understand htis. What do you call "custom partition"?

Comment: @MarcusMüller here i want to say that at the time of installation if we create only /(root) and boot partition, but when we see the /(root) directory file system we find multiple directories that we did not created at the time of installation like home, root, bin, var so these all are auto created by OS . So if these all can be auto created why we create partition of home, var etc at the time installation?

Comment: a the question is just "why do we put /home onto a separate file system, and not also things like /usr or /var?", right?

Comment: yes, exactly this is what i want to ask.

Comment: addressed in the answer

Answer (score 3):

> Why all these are inside the root if we created the different partition of home, root .why this is not separate? (i know Every directory/file in the Linux filesystem is nested under the root / directory)

Because unlike the "classic" Windows, there's a common root of the directory tree.

Why should it be separate? This is just a design choice Microsoft made for MS-DOS in 1980, based on a competitor's design¹! By the way, even Windows under the hood doesn't see "C:", "D:" and so on as "roots" of filesystems anymore; internally, there are unified representations (e.g. `\\?\C:\Windows`).

> Is the home partition(we created at the time of installation) and home directory inside /(root) same?

Yes/No. The partition is literally the part of the hard drive you assigned to store what is called a *file system*. A file system is just a big data structure containing information about files and the file data itself. Think of it as database, which is designed to fill exactly the partition space it got!

The `/home` directory is a directory, where this file system was *mounted*. In other words, the file system "database" is opened, and the contents (files and directories!) of that "database" is visible as contents of `/home`.

So, the partition is the physical space where the data gets stored in some well-defined format, and the `/home` directory is where it becomes accessible as files and directories.

If you want a human analogy: The partition is the book, the `/home` directory is the knowledge you get from reading that book.

> why do we put /home onto a separate file system, and not also things like /usr or /var?

Because it is sometimes advantageous if you can just make a complete backup of your /home, because that's where *all* the important data/documents are that you cannot simply install again.

This is a relatively weak argument on modern systems if your backup strategy is not based on partitions. There's also performance considerations, but these also not really apply on single-user single-storage machines.

It might simply be down to historic preference of a group of system admins! The whole system will work even if you do *not* make a separate partition for /home.

/boot is a bit special, there's technical reasons (the computer needs /boot to boot even before it can have loaded all the things needed to understand the data on all other partitions).

swap is not actually something mounted somewhere.

---

Historical perspective: The idea that you partition your view at data as beeing "rooted" in the actual device / partition carrying the data comes, as far as I can tell, from an operating system called CP/M, from 1974.
MS-DOS, which became the standard operating system for IBM PCs after IBM's negotiations with the company behind CP/M failed, adopted that scheme. At the same time, UNIX already existed, and had a different model – the model you still observe in Linux, where you *mount* filesystems on subdirectories.
So, technically, CP/M deliberately chose a different design for the directory tree layout for microcomputers than at least one of the datacenter operating systems of the day went with, and it would be just as valid to ask why CP/M / DOS chose this way, and why, on earth, WindowsNT, which your current Windows is based on, chose to stick with that, instead of going with the flow. Unlike Windows95, Windows NT/2000/XP/Vista/7/8/10/11 are *not* descendants or try to be compatible with MS-DOS or CP/M.

Comment: It’s still not a design decision by Microsoft ;-). If anything, it’s a design decision by Tim Paterson, who chose to reproduce the CP/M design in QDOS. When CP/M was created, there were many operating systems to choose from, so not going with the Unix model is perfectly reasonable. In 1974, Unix had only just started spreading outside Bell Labs; in the spring of 1975 there were three dozen sites with Unix installations. Compared to IBM or Digital operating systems it was very rare.

Comment: @StephenKitt learning here! Now the question is, do I work your comment into my answer or just let it stand? I'm tending towards the latter.

Comment: There might have been arguments for putting /home on a seperate partition that were about backup, but I've always heard arguments about preserving the contents of it in case of a reinstall (that wipes the filesystems it touched).

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity The original arguments were about disk utilization, not backups or preservation on reinstall. ‘Classic’ UNIX systems like 4.4 BSD or SunOS used split partitioning schemes because they generally needed more than the few dozen _megabytes_ of disk space you could get on a single physical disk in those days. The space required by the OS has scaled up, on average, much more slowly than the cost of storage, so today it’s not really a consideration, but back then you put `/home`, and `/usr`, and `/var` on separate physical drives, not just different partitions.